# How are transaction hashes generated

Tags: transactions, wallets, hash, identity

I am trying to find out if each transaction hash created by a wallet has some similarity or if every hash is "random".

I suppose my original question leads into whether or not a transaction hash  be used to identify the wallet it came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure of generating the transaction is the same, but the value will always be pseudo random due to the nature of hash function. [This post](https://medium.com/@codetractio/inside-an-ethereum-transaction-fa94ffca912f) will be a good one to refer.

However if the network is public, given the transaction hash, it is possible to get the transaction details using the web3 api as documented [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransaction). It will return the address of the account where it came from.

> from: String, 20 Bytes - address of the sender